# How to create a video stream from a single dynamic image in PHP

Tags: php, video-streaming

I have a single image file on my server which its content changes every 100 ms.

I can load and serve this image as usual:

```php
$image = file_get_contents('path/to/image.jpg');
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $image;
```

```html
<img src="image.php">
```

Thus, every time the user updates the screen (pressing F5 for example) the server would reply a different image. I can also use Java Script (using `setInterval` for example) to update the image continuously so the users needn't to update the screen themselves.

However, I need to serve this image as a CONTINUOUS FLOW such as a LIVE VIDEO STREAM in order to be shown as an HTML5 video instead of a static image.

Some examples I`ve found so far use PHP-FFMpeg library for stream videos. It turns out that those examples require that I have a video file at hand (a file in the OS or a URL to a file) instead of a single (dynamic) image as I've described above.

I found [this example](https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial) for how to use PHP to streaming. It looks promisssing. But again the code supposes I have a video file url which I haven't.

I'm wondering if is it possible to adapt this code to my needs. For example, how to adapt the `setHeader()` method to the scenario where there are no begin and end? And considering that I have loaded the image contents using `file_get_contents` or so, how to change `stream()` properly? Or, at other hand, is there other way to serve this image as a video stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just found a solution for my needs:

```
$identifier = "an_identifier";

//set headers
header('Accept-Range: bytes');
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=' . $identifier);
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

// loop to continuously serve an image
while(true) {

    $image = load_image_contents();

    echo "--" . $identifier . "\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: ".strlen($image)."\r\n\r\n".$image;
    flush();
    usleep(50000);

}
```

On the browser side I just set a regular image tag:

```
<img src="image.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should reload the image ever 200 ms. Adding a random number avoids any potential caching which is unlikely since you are requesting a PHP page.

```
<html>
    <header>
    
        <script>
        
            function ReloadImage()
            {
                var image_element = document.getElementById('image_id');
                
                image_element.src = 'image.php?rand=' + Math.random();
            }

            setInterval(ReloadImage,200);
        
        </script>
        
    </header>

    <body>

        <img src="image.php" id="image_id">
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Markus but as I pointed out I already use this approach with a slighty difference I use setTimeout instead. I am actually looking for how to generate the video flow to be opened as a HTML 5 video.